# Updating database on each http request with ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack, httplistenerrequest

Assuming I want to keep track of LastVisited field in a DB and I want to update it on each incoming request whether its hitting a ServiceStack API or an MVC Controller. What would be the best way of handling it? Obviously I can put the logic in the Global asax which will run on each request, but how would I access the session object from ServiceStack? or is there a an http handler I can attach to where the ServiceStack's session is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

and

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
```

These will override methods that are part of the `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class.

We override this class with a base controller which all our controllers inherit from.  You could use either of these for what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you that works, for ServiceStack API you would also need something like this:                                                 this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
                {
                    var customUserSession = SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession<CustomUserSession>(cacheClient); //any logic here which will run on each api request
                });